# How to initialize AVAudioPlayer using Swift

Tags: ios, audio, swift, avaudioplayer

> I'm creating a game using Swift and SpriteKit in Xcode 6.1 and I can't
>   get AVAudioPlayer to initialize. I have an SKScene for my menu, and I
>   want to run music in my "Sounds" folder called "menu.mp3." However, it
>   crashes every time I run my game. My code is below:

```
let filePath:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "menu.mp3")!
var er:NSError?
let audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePath, error: &er)

if (er != nil) {
} else {
     audioPlayer.play()
}
```

I put this in my initializer right after my super.init call. The error I get follows:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

> I've tried a lot of fixes, but I can't figure out what's going wrong.
>   I've added the AVFoundation framework and imported it to this scene,
>   but it continues to crash. Is there something wrong with my filePath
>   that makes my audioPlayer not initialize or something? I've tried
>   switching to other ways and making different parts optional, but I
>   can't get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as NSURL
func preparePlayer(name:String){
    var error:NSError?

    let fileUrl = documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(name)
//    or 
//    let fileUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(name)

    let audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileUrl, error: &error)
    if error == nil {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    preparePlayer("menu.mp3")
}
```